# Do links proving notability have to be in English?

Tags: discussion, language

I read French and I sometimes see things that could be asked on Skeptics. Is it a problem if the article/book/other making the claim is in French, and if no English equivalent can be found ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't see any problems with this, though you should provide a translation of the important part containing the claim. You post needs to be understandable by someone only speaking english, but sources can be in different languages.

Answer (score 4):

Sources don't have to be in English. It would be useful for you to provide a translated quote of when the claim is made, for users who don't speak the language of the source, but it's not mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

It should be OK as long as there's a somewhat reliable way of telling that the claim translation (which, as other alluded to, ought to be required) is accurate - either the poster is bilingually fluent, or it's a language that one of the standard translation web services is reliable with (and the language isn't too technical/idiomatic to trip up Google Translate).